# Creating BI Report in Project Server 2013

Tags: project-server

Could you please suggest me what tool and services should use in Project Server 2013 for creating BI Reports.

1. I need to create a report where I want to use Enterprise custom field like Country etc in the first BI report. How should I get Enterprise Custom Field on the report?
2. I need to show some Project status indicator on second chart if project progress is lagging behind date.

   [image]

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is more than a year old, but I wanted to respond just in case it could still help you or someone else.

There are MANY different ways of reporting in Project Server.  It appears you are looking for a dashboard.  Based solely on your question (we really need more information), I would look at some of the offerings using PerformancePoint.  PerformancePoint is an excellent tool for doing all sorts of dashboards.

Good Luck!

K